# Anyway to remove fractions from a matrix to make them easier to work with?

Tags: matrices

For example:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1/4 & 0 \\
    0 & 1/6  \\
  \end{bmatrix}

Is there a way to factor anything out to make this matrix easier for multiplication? Like if they were both 1/4, I could have factored $1/4$ out and they would be a basic identity matrix

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac14 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac16 \end{bmatrix} = \frac1{12} \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @WillJagy I wouldn't. I would be quite worried if someone is doing matrices but does not know LCM.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out <strike>anything</strike> any number you want to (except zero):

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{k} \begin{bmatrix}  ak &  bk \\  ck &  dk \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You should be careful - by "anything" you mean "any scalar." You can, of course, factor it into other matrices, but that doesn't, in general, help with multiplication.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Disagree--in the context of the problem, this answer is completely clear. Begrudgingly corrected, nonetheless.